# sshdOpenSSL version mismatch - update sshd from rescue mode

Tags: linux, ssh, debian

After upgrading with `apt-get upgrade` then `sshd` is not starting at boot

## upgrade

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

## error on boot

[image]

Have tried to boot in rescue mode and run the following command to update `sshd` but it doesn't work. After rebooting `sshd` still fails to load at boot and return the same error about version mismatch

```
apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

How to update the openssl version in `sshd` from rescue mode so the versions match?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24096069/openssl-version-mismatch-built-against-1000105f-you-have-10001080

Comment: thats exactly what I'm trying to do :)

Comment: You had to guarantee that your sshd have the same version as your openssl lib. Use some `dpkg -L|grep something`, some `ldconfig -p|grep -i ssl` and such.

Comment: could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: the system is in rescue mode..

Comment: What does rescue mode mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution

## Update openssh from rescue mode

Mounting the hard drive in rescue mode (with software RAID)

```
# mount /dev/md2 /mnt
# mount -o bind /dev /mnt/dev
# mount -o bind /sys /mnt/sys
# mount -o bind /dev/shm /mnt/dev/shm
# mount -o bind /proc /mnt/proc
# chroot /mnt
```

Updating openssh

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

Restart the server and the server will boot up in normal mode

## Update openssh from a remote console

```
# apt-get update && apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

If the ssh server doesn't start, start it

```
# service ssh start
```